# Javascript regex find %3A// in a string and replace it

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How to get my regex .replace working in javascript?

My code right now:

```
var href = https://www.mailinator.com/key/url?url=https%3A//test.eu/api/
var res = href.replace(\https%3A\/\/test.eu\g', 'localhost:3000');
```

And i want to get back string which looks like this:
https://www.mailinator.com/key/url?url=localhost:3000/api/....

Comment: Right now i can match every other section of the href. But only not the %3a// part.

Comment: `var res = href.replace(\https%3A\/\/test.eu\g', 'localhost:3000');`
Should be:
`var res = href.replace(/https%3A\/\/test\.eu/', 'localhost:3000');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex has to be between a forward slashes to delimit the regex instead of a backslashes and you have to escape the dot to match it literally. You coud use `/g` global to don't return after the first match.

`https%3A\/\/test\.eu/g`

```js
var href = 'https://www.mailinator.com/key/url?url=https%3A//test.eu/api/';
var res = href.replace(/https%3A\/\/test\.eu/g, 'localhost:3000');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `(?<=url=).*(?=\/api)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kaTkIh/1)

Comment: Wow, very great solution! Didn't event think about it. Works too! (Y)